# How to get result of custom query with new field name in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my springboot application I have repository connected to the mysql. I can make query which has same response fields as the entity. But in case of native query how can I catch the new fields?

Here is my query method

```
@Repository
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<Log, String>  {

    @Query("SELECT error, COUNT(*) AS numberOfErr FROM logs GROUP BY error ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC")
    List<Log> countError();
}
```

But the Log class does not have any `numberOfErr` field. So what actually this method should return?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface:

```java
public interface LogError {
    Log getError();
    Long getNumberOfErr();
}
```

And then use it as return type for the query:

```java
@Repository
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<Log, String>  {

    @Query("SELECT error as error, COUNT(*) AS numberOfErr FROM logs GROUP BY error ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC")
    List<LogError> countError();
}
```

For more information, [see the Projections section in the Spring JPA documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).